# Toggle function won't work

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this div (in the shape of a block), which I want to move right and left by clicking on it. The idea is that the first toggle action works (meaning the block takes 250px of space from the left side) but won't move to the left after I click on it again.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#block1").click(function()
    {
        var toggleState = true;
        if (toggleState)
        {
            $("#block1").animate({left: '250px'});
        }
        else
        {
            $("#block1").animate({left: '250px'});
        }
        toggleState = !toggleState;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your end-position for both states of the toggle are also identical.

Comment: Holy... I completely missed that. Thank you :) Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `toggleState` outside the click function, otherwise its value is constantly overwritten. I've also defined the variable  with a null value and changed the `true` condition left value, but neither of those were your primary issue.

```
var toggleState;

$("#block1").click(function() {
    if (toggleState) {
        $("#block1").animate({
            left: '10px'
        });
    } else {
        $("#block1").animate({
            left: '250px'
        });
    }
    toggleState = !toggleState;
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yzkhsx9s/)**

Comment: Cough, `else {left: 0px}` cough.  Or you're just moving it to the same position as it already is.

Comment: I was leaving that to the OP. Not entirely relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You have toggleState variable inside function you need to move it outside.